# varnish: Alter response body

Tags: varnish

I need to rewrite the response received by the backend in varnish. The C-function is ready, embedded in the configuration file, and passes tests run on response headers. But I need to access the *body* of the response. I couldn't find a way to extract that from the [response struct](http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/VCL#Preparingresponse), though. Does anyone have an idea how I could extract it anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to replace the bit of the body you want changed with an ESI tag?

Comment: Maybe he does not own the content? Maybe he is a system admin that has to provide a temporary fix but can't do it with HTML which developers territory and they have a longer SDLC to go through? There are a lot of reasons to do it.